# Using WebRTC getUserMedia with UWP WebView

Tags: win-universal-app, webrtc

I've created a basic UWP application with a WebView. I'm navigating to this URL: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/ to test the use of getUserMedia().

The error I get is: getUserMedia error: NotFoundError

Does anyone know if this should be possible, and if I'm therefore doing something wrong? Anyone using getUserMedia within a UWP WebView?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> getUserMedia error: NotFoundError

This error will occurre when the user denies permission, or media is not available.

In an UWP app, when you want to access Media capture, you will need to open the manifest file of your project, go to the `Capabilities` label and select the `Webcam` capability to enable the Camera device for your app.

This will solve the problem, but for your case, I think you may also need to enable the `Microphone` capability in the same way.

Comment: Awesome - this is the exactly the help I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the accepted answer, I needed to add this handler to the webview to allow permission:

```
webView.PermissionRequested += WebView_PermissionRequested;
...
private void WebView_PermissionRequested(WebView sender, 
WebViewPermissionRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    args.PermissionRequest.Allow();
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU, this saved me a ton of time.